# how to change schema owner to system? (DB2)

Tags: sql, db2

how to change myschema owner to system?

when i try execute

> TRANSFER OWNERSHIP OF SCHEMA MYSCHEMA TO USER SYSIBM REVOKE PRIVILEGES

get error

> SQL Error [42602]: The operation failed because the specified authorization name does not meet the identifier naming rules. Authorization name: "SYSIBM".. SQLCODE=-567, SQLSTATE=42602, DRIVER=4.26.14

Comment: You issued the `TRANSFER OWNERSHIP` statement, but got an error referencing the `ALTER SCHEMA` statement. This looks strange. Check the statement terminator you use in your client. It probably tries to execute not what you really want. And you are not able to transfer ownership to SYS* users - you get SQL0567N in such a case.

Comment: sorry my mistake put wrong error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments, Db2 does not allow you to explicitly make objects (or transfer ownerships) into system schemas (those beginning with SYS*).

Those SYS* schemas are reserved for use by Db2 itself and are managed only by IBM. The reserved schema names are platform specific. So they can differ between Db2-for-i,  Db2-for-Linux/Unix/Windows, Db2-for-Z/OS.

You did not explain **why** you wanted to do such a thing, but if your real motivation was to protect `MYSCHEMA` then you must achieve your aim within the capabilities of the `REVOKE` and `GRANT` statements. Take a look at revoking from PUBLIC for example.